# Xcode 14 constantly crashing when removing Link with binary

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios16, xcode14

Xcode contantly crashing when removing link binary link with libaray. Please help i need to create a build for my app.

[image: e]

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @burnsi can't throw any message or reporting popup from apple. Just crash whole Xcode immediately.

Answer (score 0):

-- Option one --

1. Exit Xcode
2. Open the file [Your project].xcodeproj/project.pbxproj with a text editor
3. Search for all the lines that contain the phrase "SmartlookAnalytics.xcFramework" and remove them
4. Save the file and re open the project with Xcode

-- Option two --

Open the project with an older version of XCode and perform the change from the older version